# How are the location of Gausian points determined in Finite element theory?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, applied-mechanics, finite-element-method

From the finite element theory, what is remained a bit unclear for me, is that how do we know the location of gausian points where the integration is done for each specific type of element ? it is not indicated in many FEM books, but if someone could explain it here , it would be fantastic

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature#Gauss_Legendre_quadrature.  The Gauss points are called Gauss nodes in the article.  They are the $i$-th roots of the associated Legendre polynomials in [-1,1].  Isoparametric assumptions are used to convert fom [-1,1] to arbitrary coordinate ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know the location of integration points is governed by numerical method used for integration. I know only one method of numerical integration, Gauss Quadrature. For details of Gauss Quadrature, please see Wikipedia article or Introduction to Finite Element Method by J.N. Reddy.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using standard Gauss quadrature, from the formulation, you determine the coefficients (weights of Gauss location) and their locations. You cannot arbitrarily decide their locations. Here are some examples: http://edwilson.org/BOOK-Wilson/G-inter.pdf